# SLURM task fails when creating an instance of the Dask LocalCluster in an HPC cluster

Tags: python, dask, slurm

I'm queuing a task with the command `sbatch` and the next configuration:

```
#SBATCH --job-name=dask-test
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=10
#SBATCH --mem=80G
#SBATCH --time=00:30:00
#SBATCH --tmp=10G
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --qos=normal

python ./dask-test.py
```

The python script is, more or less, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

print("Generating LocalCluster...")
cluster = LocalCluster()
print("Generating Client...")
client = Client(cluster, processes=False)

print("Scaling client...")
client.scale(8)

data = dd.read_csv(
    BASE_DATA_SOURCE + '/Data-BIGDATFILES-*.csv',
    delimiter=';',
)

def get_min_dt():
    min_dt = data.datetime.min().compute()
    print("Min is {}".format())

print("Getting min dt...")
get_min_dt()
```

The first problem is that the texts "Generating LocalCluster..." is printed 6 times, which makes me wonder if the script is running multiple times concurrently.
Secondly, after some minutes of printing nothing, I receive the following messages:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/node.py:155: UserWarning: Port 8787 is already in use.
Perhaps you already have a cluster running?
Hosting the HTTP server on port 37396 instead
  http_address["port"], self.http_server.port
```

many times.. and finally the next one, also many times:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<_wrap_awaitable() done, defined at /cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py:592> exception=RuntimeError('\n        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the\n        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.\n\n        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your\n        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom\n        in the main module:\n\n            if __name__ == \'__main__\':\n                freeze_support()\n                ...\n\n        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program\n        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 599, in _wrap_awaitable
    return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 290, in _
    await self.start()
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 295, in start
    response = await self.instantiate()
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 378, in instantiate
    result = await self.process.start()
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 575, in start
    await self.process.start()
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/process.py", line 34, in _call_and_set_future
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/process.py", line 202, in _start
    process.start()
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 20, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 42, in _launch
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "/cluster/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

I already tried adding more cores, more memory, setting `processes=False` at the instantiation of `Client`, and many other things but I can't figure it out what's the problem.

The used library/software versions are:

- Python 3.7
- Pandas 1.0.5
- Dask 2.19.0
- slurm 17.11.7

Am I setting something wrong? Is the way of using local cluster and client structures correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I could get a solution. Not too sure about the cause but very sure it works.

The instantiation of LocalCluster, Client and all the code after it (the code that will be distributed executed) must NOT be at module level of the Python script. Instead, this code must be in a method or inside the __main__ block, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Generating LocalCluster...")
    cluster = LocalCluster()
    print("Generating Client...")
    client = Client(cluster, processes=False)

    print("Scaling client...")
    client.scale(8)

    data = dd.read_csv(
        BASE_DATA_SOURCE + '/Data-BIGDATFILES-*.csv',
        delimiter=';',
    )

    def get_min_dt():
        min_dt = data.datetime.min().compute()
        print("Min is {}".format())

    print("Getting min dt...")
    get_min_dt()
```

This simple change makes a difference. The solution was found in that issues thread: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2520#issuecomment-470817810

Comment: You are an absolute champion